# How can I use dplyr/magrittr's pipe inside functions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr, nse

I'm trying to write a function which takes as argument a dataframe and the name of the function. When I try to write the function with the standard R syntax, I can get the good result using `eval` and `substitute` as recommanded by @hadley in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

```
> df <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
> f <- function(data, x) {
+   out <- mean(eval(expr = substitute(x), envir = data))
+   return(out)
+ }
> f(data = df, x = y)
[1] 5.5
```

Now, when I try to write the same function using the `%>%` operator, it doesn't work :

```
> df <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
> f <- function(data, x) {
+   data %>% 
+     eval(expr = substitute(x), envir = .) %>% 
+     mean()
+ }
> f(data = df, x = y)
Show Traceback
Rerun with Debug
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objet 'y' introuvable 
>
```

How can I using the combine the piping operator with the use of `eval` and `substitute` ? It's seems really tricky for me.

Comment: the problem is not in the pipe but rather the [Non Standard Evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) used by `dplyr` functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying to understand my problem.

First, I've written what I want with the `summarise()` function :

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
> summarise_(.data = df, mean = ~mean(y))
  mean
1  5.5
```

Then I try to program my own function. I've found a solution which seems to work with the `lazyeval` package in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195525/programming-with-dplyr-and-lazyeval). I use the `lazy()` and the `interp()` functions to write what I want.

The first possibility is here :

```
> library(lazyeval)
> f <- function(data, col) {
+   col <- lazy(col)
+   inter <- interp(~mean(x), x = col)
+   summarise_(.data = data, mean = inter)    
+   }
> f(data = df, col = y)
  mean
1  5.5
```

I can also use pipes :

```
> f <- function(data, col) {
+   col <- lazy(col)
+   inter <- interp(~mean(x), x = col)
+   data %>% 
+     summarise_(.data = ., mean = inter)    
+ }
> 
> f(data = df, col = y)
  mean
1  5.5
```

Answer (score 7):

A workaround would be

```
f <- function(data, x) {
  v <- substitute(x)
  data %>% 
    eval(expr = v, envir = .) %>%
    mean()
}
```

The problem is that the pipe functions (`%>%`) are creating another level of closure which interferes with the evaluation of `substitute(x)`. You can see the difference with this example

```
df <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
f1 <- function(data, x) {
  print(environment())
  eval(expr = environment(), envir = data)
}

f2 <- function(data, x) {
  print(environment())
  data %>% 
    eval(expr = environment(), envir = .)
}
f1(data = df, x = y)
# <environment: 0x0000000006388638>
# <environment: 0x0000000006388638>
f2(data = df, x = y)
# <environment: 0x000000000638a4a8>
# <environment: 0x0000000005f91ae0>
```

Notice how the environments differ in the matrittr version. You want to take care of `substitute` stuff as soon as possible when mucking about with non-standard evaluation.

I hope your use case is a bit more complex than your example, because it seems like

```
mean(df$y)
```

would be a much easier bit of code to read.

Comment: Of course, this is just a toy example and I want to write a much more complex function :)

Comment: Your solution is elegant. However is there any more general answer to the problem of combining `substitute` with pipes ?

Comment: Hadley says that this isn't a good solution : https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/issues/45#issuecomment-184855725. So what's the good solution ?

Comment: Ask Hadley. I would suggest avoiding substitute and eval in magrittr.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use eval and substitute.

What follows is a simplified version of [this great post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-mutate-in-a-function-with-the-new-colname-as-an-argument/10399/2?u) suited to your question.

```
df <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
f <- function(data, x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  df %>% summarise(mean = mean(!!x))
   }
f(data = df, x = y)
```

There are two things happening here:

1. Tranforming the column name with `enquo()`
2. Prefixing the column with `!!`

Please see refer to the link for a more complicated example.